# Uploading file to s3 bucket without using AWS console using nodeJs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS technology, i need to do above assignment so i want to know procedure do complete above task. What are prerequisites software and tools should i required.

Please suggest me in simple way. TIN Happy Coding

Comment: Hi Shlok! Please consider adding your attempt at solving the problem to your question - for example, what you have already researched or tried. Thank you!

Comment: Hello Shlok. Welcome to StackOverflow. Kindly be more specific here, and provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have to configure your AWS credential before suing Aws with [aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk) npm package using below method

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID_OF_AMAZON,
  secretAccessKey: YOUR_AMAZON_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  signatureVersion: "v4",
  region: YOUR_AMAZON_REGION // country 
});
export { s3 };
```

then call s3 and do upload request using below code

```
const uploadReq: any = {
      Bucket: "YOUR_BUCKET"
      Key: "FILE_NAME",
      Body: "FILE_STREAM",
      ACL: "public-read", //ACCESSIBLE TO REMOTE LOCATION
    };
   await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  s3.upload(uploadReq).send(async (err: any, data: any) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("err", err);
      reject(err);
    } else {
      //database call  
      resolve("STATUS");
    }
  });
});
```